# Can't run php cli at webuser but will run as root

Tags: command-line, php, nginx, api

I am running a Magento application on a Nginx server.

nginx + php-fpm running as webuser:www

There are some function in the shell directory of Magento which run fine as root and the import run fine on our apache box.
php 5.4

This run as webuser does not work
php -f shell/importfromapi.php

but if I run as root it works fine? When I say it works fine I mean that using root I am able to confirm in the log that the api is connect and we get data. But using the webuser I get a blank response from the API

I can't find the error logs for php.

I found var/log/php-fpm/error.log but it does not log any error.

EDIT: 
Permission for php are root, should I change this?

```
ls -la /usr/bin/php
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3865896 Mar 13 15:20 /usr/bin/php
```

I have done some more debugging:

```
curl -v http://api3.codebasehq.com/projects \
-u "myuser/keycombo"
```

The above is working from my webuser so it is not that. It has to be something in the PHP

**EDIT2:**

I just checked out the app on a different server and ran the php command as the default web-user and it worked. I think it has something to do with php-fpm.

Comment: what are the permissions of `php` (`which php` and then do `ls -la /path/to/php`)?

Comment: looks like root, should I change this?

Comment: No, because others can execute `php`. If it was `-rwxr-xr--` then there would be a problem.

Comment: In your tests, did you try to run this from the commandline yourself, both as root and as www? Or are you comparing commandline root to www triggered from a cronjob or fpm?

Comment: It will do the same thing via the Cron or manually.

Comment: This is a little tricky, then. I'm under the impression the problem is environmental more than permissions. Can you compare the output of `env` in both cases? It might also help to see the contents of that script. Can you share?